# Как получить сумму данных из одной таблицы по типу и периоду времени из другой?

Tags: mysql

Есть 2 таблицы. С текущими лимитами на кол-во прочтений по книге `booksStats` и таблица со временем, когда она была прочитана `reads`. При наличии прочтений у книги за всё время, но отсутствии прочтений за период времени в результатах выводится во всех столбцах `null`, хотя надо только у `periodReads` сделать значение равным именно `0`, не `null`. Как это исправить?

Запрос, который сейчас есть:

```
SELECT readsLimit, usagePeriod, SUM(readsCounter) as periodReads
FROM booksStats
LEFT JOIN reads ON reads.bookId=booksStats.bookId
WHERE IF((reads.bookId IS NOT NULL), CASE 
    WHEN usagePeriod = 0 THEN (added BETWEEN UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND UTC_TIMESTAMP())
    WHEN usagePeriod = 1 THEN (added BETWEEN UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND UTC_TIMESTAMP())
    WHEN usagePeriod = 2 THEN (added BETWEEN UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND  UTC_TIMESTAMP())
    WHEN usagePeriod = 3 THEN (added BETWEEN UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR AND UTC_TIMESTAMP())
    ELSE added <= UTC_TIMESTAMP() END, TRUE)
```

Если у выбранной книги стоит ограничение на сутки (`usagePeriod = 2`), а в чтениях за этот период ничего нет, то выдаст:

```
readsLimit;usagePeriod;periodReads
null;null;null
```

А хотелось бы:

```
readsLimit;usagePeriod;periodReads
10000;2;0
```

Вот пример в [mysql online](https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3z2hm5kb3), только предварительно надо убрать установку `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`.

Код `CREATE`:

```
CREATE TABLE `booksStats` (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  readsLimit INTEGER NOT NULL,
  usagePeriod INTEGER not null,
  bookId INTEGER not null
);
CREATE TABLE `reads` (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  added datetime NOT NULL,
  bookId INTEGER not null,
  readsCounter INTEGER not null
);
```

Comment: *надо только у periodReads сделать значение равным именно 0, не null* [COALESCE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Comment: @Akina `COALESCE()` _возвращает первое не-NULL значение в списке или NULL если не-значений нет NULL._ Из определения. А где тут 0 делается?

Comment: А кто сказал, что значение обязано быть полем или выражением? литерал подойдёт... ```COALESCE(table.column, 0)```

Comment: @Akina Получается, чтобы при отсутствии прочтений  за период выдавалось 0, а если их вообще не было NULL, то надо в написать что-то вроде `SELECT IF((reads.bookId IS NOT NULL), NULL, COALESCE(SUM(readsCounter), 0)) as periodReads`? Хорошо, проверю

Comment: :facepalm: ```SELECT .. COALESCE(SUM(readsCounter), 0) as periodReads ..```

Comment: @Akina Ну, теперь при наличии `COALESCE` выдаются в каждой колонке `NULL`, за исключением `periodReads`, который 0 стал равен. Что-то не правильно сработало или условия дополнять надо? (Как-то `reads.bookId IS NOT NULL` по интервалам проверять?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было условия из `where` переместить на `join`. Однако мне до сих пор не понятно, почему при левом соединении, колонки левой таблицы были `null`, когда условие на промежуток не срабатывало. Должен же вернуться пустой запрос т.к. получилось что-то вроде `where false`.

Исправленный запрос:

```
SELECT readsLimit, usagePeriod, SUM(readsCounter) as periodReads
FROM booksStats
LEFT JOIN reads ON reads.bookId=booksStats.bookId AND IF((reads.bookId IS NOT NULL), CASE 
    WHEN usagePeriod = 0 THEN (added >= UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    WHEN usagePeriod = 1 THEN (added >= UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
    WHEN usagePeriod = 2 THEN (added >= UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    WHEN usagePeriod = 3 THEN (added >= UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
    ELSE added <= UTC_TIMESTAMP() END, TRUE)
WHERE booksStats.bookId = 5
```